# Как изменить форматированный вывод данных с printf на cout?

Tags: c++, c

Как можно изменить в программе вывод данных с `printf` на `cout`?
Код программы:

```
  #include <math.h>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <cmath>
  #include <conio.h>
  #include <string>
  #include <windows.h>
  using namespace std;
  const int dlx = 6;
  const int dlxx = 3;
  const int dly = 15;
  const int dlyy = 8;
  const int col = 2;
  const int str = 10;
  const double e = 2.718281828459045;
  const double PI = 3.14159265;
  void func(double& x, double& y, double p)
  {
    if (x > atan(p)) {
    y = pow(log10(1 + abs(p * x)), 2);
  }
  else y = y = ((cos(x * x) / (4 + p)) / pow(PI + x * x, 1 / 3));
  }
  void table()
  {
     int i, j;
     for (j = 1; j <= col; j++) {
     cout << "! ";
     for (i = 1; i <= dlx; i++)
        cout << "-";
     cout << " ! ";
    for (i = 1; i <= dly; i++)
        cout << "-";
    cout << " !";
  }
cout << endl;
}
int main()
{
   SetConsoleCP(1251);
   SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
   const double xn = -2.0, xk = 4.0;
   double y, x, h = 0.02, p;
   int page = 1, i = 0, j = 0, ii = 0, jj = 0, output;
   do
   {
     cout << "Введите параметр P в пределе |P|<=5";
     cin >> p;
   } while (abs(p) >= 5);
   cout << "Введите вывод значения функции (1) научный (2) с плавающей точкой";
   cin >> output;
   x = xn;
   while (x <= xk + h) {
      system("cls");
      cout << "PAGE # " << page << endl;
      cout << "\t" << "\t" << "\t" << "\t";
      cout << "Таблица значений функции" << endl;
      cout << "\t" << "\t" << "\t" << "\t";
      cout << "При P = " << p << endl;
      table();
      for (i = 1; (i <= str) && (x <= xk + h); i++)
      {
          for (j = 1; (j <= col) && (x <= xk + h); j++)
          {
             func(x, y, p);
             cout << "! ";
            
             printf("%*.*lf", dlx, dlxx, x); //изменить здесь
             cout << " ! ";
             if (output == 1)
             {
                printf("%*e !", dly, y); //Изменить здесь
             }
             else
                 printf("%*.*lf !", dly, dlyy, y); //изменить здесь
             x = x + h;
             }
             cout << endl;
             table();
     }
    _getch();
    page++;
   }
```

}

Comment: @EOF, пробовал, но именно с числами не получается

Comment: Уверены, что это улучшит программу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот пример с использованием [`iomanip`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip) (это заголовчный файл, который нужно подключить). Вот что используется:

- `setw` устанавливает ширину поля вывода
- `setprecision` устанавливает количество знаков после десятичной точки
- `fixed` устанавливет режим отображения с плавающей точкой даже для больших чисел
- `scientific` устанавливает научную нотацию (это как режим `e` для `printf`)

```
//printf("%*.*lf", dlx, dlxx, x);
cout << fixed << setw(dlx) << setprecision(dlxx) << x;

//printf("%*e !", dly, y);
cout << scientific << setw(dly) << y << " !";

//printf("%*.*lf !", dly, dlyy, y);
cout << fixed << setw(dly) << setprecision(dlyy) << y << " !";
```